# How to get rid of "Click to add event" in infragistics' XamMonthView?

Tags: wpf, infragistics, controltemplate

I need to get rid of the "Click to add event" button that's showing up after a second when hovering over a day in infragistics' XamMonthCalendar control. I found just nothing than broken links in the web until now. I tried to "edit a copy" of the control template, but I just got this in the first place and I don't know how to dig deeper into it. Seems like I would have to modify ScheduleStackPanel. Could anyone show me a path?

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type igSchedule:XamMonthView}">
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igSchedule:XamMonthView}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <Grid x:Name="RootPanel">
                            <ig:GridBagPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                                <igSchedulePrim:ScheduleStackPanel x:Name="GroupHeadersPanel" Visibility="{TemplateBinding CalendarHeaderAreaVisibilityResolved}"/>
                                <igSchedulePrim:ScheduleStackPanel x:Name="GroupsPanel"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="WeekScrollBar" Orientation="Vertical" Style="{TemplateBinding ScrollBarStyle}"/>
                                <ScrollBar x:Name="TimeslotGroupScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Style="{TemplateBinding ScrollBarStyle}"/>
                            </ig:GridBagPanel>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ErrorDisplay" Content="{Binding BlockingError, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource BlockingErrorStyle}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xamMonthView is just one of the schedule view controls so the settings that affect that functionality are on the component that provides the schedule data - the xamScheduleDataManager. To disable that ability one would set the [IsAddViaClickToAddEnabled](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.controls.schedules%7Einfragistics.controls.schedules.activitysettings%7Eisaddviaclicktoaddenabled) to false for the [AppointmentSettings](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.controls.schedules%7Einfragistics.controls.schedules.appointmentsettings) of the [Settings](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.controls.schedules%7Einfragistics.controls.schedules.xamscheduledatamanager%7Esettings) of the [XamScheduleDataManager](https://www.infragistics.com/help/wpf/infragisticswpf.controls.schedules%7Einfragistics.controls.schedules.xamscheduledatamanager). Note you might/probably need to set that to false for all the activity types - namely TaskSettings and JournalSettings too.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I couldn't find the documentation on this.